# Does Yii2 take care of the important security concerns?

Tags: yii2

while storing url's in MySql database in php, 
I had to use the following,
`mysql_real_escape_string('xyz/xyz.html')`
mysql is deprecated, and Now I use Yii 2.0 (the authors claims it is secure).

I used it's Gii CRUD and through this now the url's are stored easily, no escaping required.

(If it uses PDO probably the prepared statements take care of the above problem)

I wonder whether Yii-2.0 takes cares of the important security concerns related to storing things in the database and then spitting them out on views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Yii2 uses PDO at performing SQL queries, however I not recommend to hope, that it saves you from all potential security problems.
I usually recommend 2 preventive rules:

- filtration all user input strings before save,
- encoding all these
  strings at displaying in the view.

I will describe example for your case, when you work with URLs. It will demonstrate few Yii2 features that may help you to improve application safety.

1. **Filtration before save**.

If you used CRUD for creating Models and Controllers, you need small modification in `ActiveRecord::rules()` method (in model that stores url):

```
class SomeActiveRecord extents ActiveRecord {
    // ...

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [ ['attribute_that_store_url', 'url'] ],
        ];
    }
}
```

This code validates value that will loaded from form. [More details about this validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#url)

2. **Encoding before diplaying**.

When you want to display this values using [DetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html) (by default for CRUD generated view), you can use built-in [formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$attributes-detail):

```
echo DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'attribute_that_store_url:url'
        'title',                        // title attribute (in plain text)
        'description:html',             // description attribute in HTML
        [                               // the owner name of the model
            'label' => 'Owner',
            'value' => Html::encode($model->owner->name),
        ],
        'created_at:datetime',          // creation date formatted as datetime
    ],
]);
```

All available formatters you can find in class `yii\i18n\Formatter`, for example URL will be preprossed by method [yii\i18n\Formatter::asUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asUrl()-detail).
In more complex cases when you want to display values manually (without similar widgets), you can access this formatter as application component via `Yii::$app->formatter`.

Moreover you can encode values using `Html::encode`, more details here: [Encoding and Decoding Content](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#encoding-and-decoding-content)

For preprocessing html before displaying can be used [HtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html) that allows to keep only certain tags.

Moreover for reading: [Security best practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#basic-principles)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The `save()` method take care of SQL Injection. The same applies to `QueryBuilder`.

For XSS attacks you have to escape user input before rendering it using `Html::encode($var)` or using `\yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($this->$attribute)` before save it into the database.

CRSF validation is automatically handled by Yii out of the box.

More info at:

[ActiveRecord](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md)

[QueryBuilder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html)

[Command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html)

[Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html)

[Active Record Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)

[Security Best Practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Yii does take care of the security things.

> If it uses PDO probably the prepared statements take care of the above problem

Yes, Yii uses PDO prepared statements everywhere, so usually no escaping required. There are only two exceptions with SQL queries, where you have to take care of binding prepared statements yourself:

- plain SQL queries built with [Database Access Objects (DAO)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html). When you compose a plain SQL query, leave data placeholders and bind parameters as described in the article [DAO - Parameters Binding](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#binding-parameters)
- Using [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) is a sure way for safe SQL. All the input data gets bound or escaped by default, no manual escaping required unless you want to insert a plain SQL, for example as a complex `WHERE` condition. Then you must use [\yii\db\Expression()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) and remember that it will go to SQL exactly as you wrote it - manual data binding is required.

Views rendering can be dangerous because of possibility of cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. To avoid it, always use output filtering as it is described in the [Views Security](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#security) guide article.

Read [Security best practices](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html) guide article to learn more and build secure applications